# mysql search in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, search

**Q:** How can i make mysql query search in multiple rows

What i want to make script search is:

```
if kat_preces_params.params_id is equal to 124 AND kat_preces_params.nosaukums is  LIKE '%$make%',

AND if kat_preces_params.params_id is equal to 125 AND kat_preces_params.nosaukums is LIKE '%$model%' 

AND IF kat_preces_params.params_id is equal to 126 AND kat_preces_params.nosaukums <=2009 AND kat_preces_params.nosaukums >=2000
```

**How i tried to do it (i know it's wrong, 'cause it doesn't display right values...):**

PHP checking the year:

```
if($year == '2010 - ...'){
    $gads = 'kat_preces_params.nosaukums <=2010';
}
elseif($year == '2000 - 2009'){
    $gads = 'kat_preces_params.nosaukums <=2009 AND kat_preces_params.nosaukums >=2000';
}
elseif($year == '2000 - 2004'){
    $gads = "kat_preces_params.nosaukums <=2004 AND kat_preces_params.nosaukums >= 2000";
}
elseif($year == '... - 1999'){
    $gads = "kat_preces_params.nosaukums <=1991";

}
```

AND I have a mysql query looking like this:

```
SELECT kat_prece.*, kat_preces_params.* FROM kat_prece, kat_preces_params WHERE pamat_kat_sad = '$cat_mod_id' 
AND kat_prece.preces_id = kat_preces_params.preces_id 
AND ((
    kat_preces_params.params_id=124 
    AND kat_preces_params.nosaukums LIKE '%$make%'
    ) 
    || (
        kat_preces_params.params_id=125 
        AND kat_preces_params.nosaukums LIKE '%$model%'
        ) 
    AND kat_preces_params.params_id=126 
    AND $gads
    )
```

`$model` and `$make` are requested values

Maybe it's possible with `INNER JOIN` or somehow (don't know nothing about inner join)?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Did you tried that query? What's wrong? Do you have errors? Which ones?

Comment: What actually is the datattype for `kat_preces_params.nosaukums`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Change the `$gads` definition to this: `kat_preces_params.nosaukums BETWEEN 2000 AND 2009` and so on.
- From your first set of prerequisites, I think what you need is something like: `kat_preces_params.params_id IN (124, 125, 126) AND kat_preces_params.nosaukums LIKE '%$make%' OR kat_preces_params.nosaukums LIKE '%$model%'`.

What I don't understand is that what type of data is there in `kat_preces_params.nosaukums` where you are once comparing them as **INTEGER** and another time, as **STRINGS**.

Comment: `kat_preces_params.nosaukums` datatype is longtext

Comment: @Pēteris Can you provide a sample table on sqlfiddle? Also, please explain what kind of output you want with an example.